# How to connect to remote OPC server

Tags: c#, plc, opc, opc-da

I am trying to connect to OPC server which is present in a remote PC in LAN. Here is the code

```
ObjOPCServer.Connect(OPCServerName, "192.168.1.5");
```

`192.168.1.5` is the IP of the remote PC. Now I want to know where could I put the username & the password of the remote PC to connect to, since the remote PC contains a username & a password.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use OPC DA, you have to do OPC DCOM settings. And if you are connecting to the remote PC, make sure you have the same user name in both local and remote machine and this user have rights to access the OPC enum service.

Check this link, it contains all the details related to opc remote settings.

[Dcom settings](https://www.kepware.com/support/resource-library/connectivity-guides/remote-opc-da-dcom.pdf)

Comment: Yes, I am using OPC DA. No, the usernames are different Isn't there something like setting login credentials of the remote PC to access it.

Comment: I also try to find this feature long before, but not succeeded, looks like remote machine maps the user name and then grant the permissions in opc enum service. I would also like to know if passing username is possible, but till i know its not possible.

Comment: Check this out this white paper from opc foundation : http://www.sytech.com/download/OPC_and_DCOM.pdf         Here for establishing OPC communication u must remove window security and setup mutual user configuration.

Comment: I am currently trying to connect a software application to a Siemens OPC server, but the connection requires a "Server Prog ID" and I cannot seem to get it down right - is there somewhere I can go to look up some help for this? (The connection is on a CPC to a PLC using DP profibus)